# Hair particles/fur goes through mesh and is behaving weird randomly on moving object/armature

Tags: particles, hair

I have a low poly figure with three separate particle systems of hair that is combed and modified with  Particle Edit. I´m playing around with making the hair move and react. I have baked all three of them.

**Problem 1:** When the arm moves up the hair on the upper part of the arm dissapears through the arms mesh... how do I make it not do that?

**Problem 2:** When rendered; the particle system with short hair behaves weird. It looks and acts fine mostly  through out the anmimation - except for certain few frames here and there when moving. It goes haywire wild and huge/dragged out...!?

**EDIT: I tried sizeing down it since it was a huge figure. Now when I bake and try the hair still goes wild. Before baking the hair followed the armature fine on frame 1... but after that the armature and mesh goes on its own through the hair. Whats going on?**

**EDIT 2:
Disabeling Hair Dynamics solves the hair going wild... but when I tried appending it in a new file/project and then turn om Dynamics - it´s still the same (se video/GIF below).**

[image: Hair goes wild]

ADDED: BLEND-file
[image]

Comment: maybe first in the modifiers stack put the Armature above the ParticleSystem? And also in the Particle System panel > Emission > Source, enable Use Modifier Stack?

Comment: Armature is above. Tried with the modifier stack. Still doesnt work...

Comment: if you disabke Hair Dynamics it won't happen anymore, also if I append your objects in a new file it seems to work fine, I don't know why...

Comment: But later on when I want the hair to react to motion (charachter walking/jumping etc) and wind.... will I not have to enable Hair Dynamics?

Comment: If you append your objects in a new file it will work with hair dynamics, i don't know why, so you can keep the option

Comment: OK.... so one last, possibly stupid question; how do I append an object? I have only appended materials before....

Comment: File > Append > double click on the blend file > Object > select all the objects and OK

Comment: It has something to do with your Particle Edit of 'KROPP'.  If I delete the edit, all behaves well.  I tried playing with Pin Goal Strength, Collision Quality, and Impulse Clamping (very useful in Cloth fly-away problems) with no luck.

Comment: "the armature and mesh goes on its own through the hair" -- try adding a collision object to the cube.

Comment: Thanks for your effort James. This is annoying... I want to be able to edit the hair manually (particle edit) and still use with dynamics... anyone else have any idea how to solve this?